# Postgresql query to retrieve parents with all children orderered by depth

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, tree

suppose i have the following tables:

Table **accounts** :

```
parent_id | id

......
10         | 101
20         | 201
30         | 301
30         | 302
40         | 401
40         | 402
401        | 4011
401        | 4012
4012       | 40121
```

and table **accounts_tree** :

```
ancestor | descentant | depth

1         | 10         | 1
1         | 20         | 1
1         | 30         | 1
1         | 40         | 1
1         | 101        | 2
1         | 201        | 2
1         | 301        | 2
1         | 302        | 2
1         | 401        | 2
1         | 402        | 2
1         | 4011       | 3
1         | 4012       | 3
1         | 40121      | 4
10        | 101        | 1
20        | 201        | 1
30        | 301        | 1
30        | 302        | 1
40        | 401        | 1
40        | 402        | 1
40        | 4011       | 2
40        | 4012       | 2
40        | 40121      | 3
401       | 4011       | 1
401       | 4012       | 1
4012      | 40121      | 1
```

What i need is to display the account id's (parents) with all their  childrens, and for each children display their childrens, grouped by depth ascending;
So far i used :

```
SELECT
    a.parent_id,
    a.id,
    p.depth
FROM
    accounts a
    INNER JOIN account_tree p ON a.id = p.descendant
    WHERE
        p.ancestor = 1
        AND p.depth <= 4
    ORDER BY
        a.parent_id;
```

which is returning all the accounts ordered by parent id.
My expectations are :

```
parent_id | id        | depth

1         | 10         | 1
10        | 101        | 2
1         | 20         | 1
20        | 201        | 2
1         | 30         | 1
30        | 301        | 2
30        | 302        | 2
1         | 40         | 1
40        | 401        | 2
401       | 4011       | 3
401       | 4012       | 3
4012      | 40121      | 4
40        | 402        | 2
```

I must mention that in the project that i am working on, there are 500+ accounts, and their id's are not that 'predictable' numbered as in my example, and the depth goes above 5 levels.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting TomC's answer to postgres

```
with recursive tree as (
    select parent_id, id, lpad(id::varchar(12),12,'0')::varchar(144) as idPath, 1::int as depth 
    from accounts 
    where parent_id = '1'
    union all 
    select a.parent_id, a.id, concat(idPath, lpad(a.id,12,'0'))::varchar(144)  idPath, depth + 1::int as depth
    from accounts a
    join tree on tree.id=a.parent_id
)
select parent_id, id, depth, idpath
from tree 
order by idpath
```

If you use lpad() dissimilar lengths of the account string at any level don't bias the overall order. You need to choose lengths that suit your actual account numbers. I have used 12, and the concatenated path needs to be a multiple of whatever number you choose.

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|    | parent_id | id    | depth | idpath                                           |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1         | 10    | 1     | 000000000010                                     |
| 2  | 10        | 101   | 2     | 000000000010000000000101                         |
| 3  | 1         | 20    | 1     | 000000000020                                     |
| 4  | 20        | 201   | 2     | 000000000020000000000201                         |
| 5  | 1         | 30    | 1     | 000000000030                                     |
| 6  | 30        | 301   | 2     | 000000000030000000000301                         |
| 7  | 30        | 302   | 2     | 000000000030000000000302                         |
| 8  | 1         | 40    | 1     | 000000000040                                     |
| 9  | 40        | 401   | 2     | 000000000040000000000401                         |
| 10 | 401       | 4011  | 3     | 000000000040000000000401000000004011             |
| 11 | 401       | 4012  | 3     | 000000000040000000000401000000004012             |
| 12 | 4012      | 40121 | 4     | 000000000040000000000401000000004012000000040121 |
| 13 | 40        | 402   | 2     | 000000000040000000000402                         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

sample data used:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
   parent_id VARCHAR(12) 
  ,id        VARCHAR(12) 
);
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('1','10');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('1','20');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('1','30');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('1','40');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('10','101');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('20','201');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('30','301');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('30','302');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('40','401');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('40','402');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('401','4011');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('401','4012');
INSERT INTO accounts(parent_id,id) VALUES ('4012','40121');
```

Comment: You have found an interesting issue in the OP's question - the sample data would work whether its padded integers or not - interesting to see if its needed or not. Probably is. Thanks for the Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for a recursive CTE. I'm assuming that your keys are actually varchar as they are not representing numeric values - if not then update as per my last piece.

This will create the test data. you only need your Account table, not your tree table

```
create table #account(parent_id varchar(10), id varchar(10))
insert #account values ('1','10'),('1','20'),('1','30'),('1','40'),('10','101'),('20','201'),('30','301')
    ,('30','302'),('40','401'),('40','402'),('401','4011'),('401','4012'),('4012','40121')
```

Now your recursive query, first find all the top level rows (parent = 1), then find all children, building up a compound path as we go

```
;with tree as (
    select parent_id, id, convert(varchar(100),id) as idPath, 1 as depth 
    from #account 
    where parent_id=1
    union all 
    select a.parent_id, a.id, convert(varchar(100),idPath+a.id) as idPath, depth+1 as depth
    from #account a
    join tree on tree.id=a.parent_id
)
select parent_id, id, depth from tree order by idpath
```

If the id's are actually integer data type, then change the concatenation to

```
convert(varchar(100),convert(varchar(10),idPath)+convert(varchar(10),a.id)) as idPath
```

Comment: All the data is bigint, depth is integer. My accounts are like this (example): parent_id 807 has childrens like 23456, 39887,12345